# UIScrollView always snaps back

Tags: uiscrollview

I put a bunch of objects into a UIScrollView and I no have a problem: When I try to "scroll" to some off-screen objects, they appear so long as I am holding my finger down after dragging it, but when I let you, the UIScrollView snaps back to the original position.

Is there a way to prevent this? No off-screen gray area is appaering when this happens, BTW.

Thanks.

Comment: @jtbandes: i have almost 10 objects on my scrollview and they are horizontally aligned. my scrollviews' content size is more than 2000. so i can scroll enough towards right side. But when i want to scroll towards left, the scrollview bounces back like rubberband. Can u help me in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077550/uiscrollview-dragging-towards-right-snaps-back

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to set the scroll view's [`contentSize`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentSize) to include your objects, so it knows how large the scrollable area is — how far to scroll freely before it hits the edge and bounces back.

Comment: This is going to sound odd but this isn't working part of the time..... Sometimes it still snaps back. CGSize size = CGSizeMake(1000, 1000); scrollview.contentSize = size;

Comment: Are you trying to create an infinite scroll view? If so there's a good WWDC video about it.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a **Content Size Fitter** component to the Scroll View's **Content** object and set its scroll direction (Horizontal Fit or Vertical Fit) to **Preferred Size**.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer for me